# Runtime is not ready for debugging when running a React-Native

Tags: ios, react-native, fatal-error, metro-bundler

Why am i getting this error even though I cleaned the pod file in VS Code when running a React-Native project.

[image]

I used `npx react-native run-ios` to run the project. This is the first react native project I made and I can't get over this error.